# Conversion of date time using pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, datetime

I have time column in format of

```
Feb 21, 2019 5:50:39 PM
```

When I do

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

then the time gets convert to

```
2019-02-21 17:50:39
```

But when I am using the input data with milliseconds like this- Feb 21, 2019 5:50:39:2 PM. Then it is giving the

```
error -> ValueError: (u'Unknown string format:', 'Feb 21, 2019 5:50:39:2 PM')
```

I need the same output as I have for without millisecond to have with milliseconds as well.

**Expected output** 2019-02-21 17:50:39:2

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to read, can you please fix the formatting and provide some sample data to test with please?

Comment: looks like the `pd.to_datime` is removing the milisecond data and OP wants to keep it

Comment: I want to keep the millisecond data but when I pass the input with millisecond it gives an error which I mentioned above and when I pass input without millisecond then It gives output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
t='Feb 21, 2019 5:50:39 PM'
new=pd.to_datetime(t,format='%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

---

```
2019-02-21 05:50:39
```

Comment: I need the input with millisecond and output with millisecond too.

Comment: ValueError: time data 'Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39:1 PM' does not match format '%b %d,%Y %H:%M:%S %p' (match)  This the error I am getting running this code.

Comment: @is0707 it is better this way ;)

Comment: Hi prosti, I tried with format='%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S:f %p' and I am getting the required output. Thanks for your help.